# how to call fragment having no layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments FileManage and another is FragmentA. FileManage has no layout of it's own but FileManage class wants to call FragmentA .so how can be This Possible . i have tried code given below but it is not working

```
FragmentA f12 =new FragmentA();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(0, f12);
transaction.commit();
```

Normally here in replace function we put 1st Paramtere as layout of base Activity ..but here i have no layout so what to do???

Comment: have you tried add(Fragment fragment, String tag) ?

Comment: yes it's not working..welll i want to replace the fragment not add

Comment: then add a dummylayout to the fragment you want to replace. empty layout with an id, so you can replace it

Comment: actually i have long programming code for file manager and i have made list view through coding.now if i adding a blank layout it is giving me a error..

Comment: i thought that there was no id in your first fragment, that you want to replace? so if there is something in the fragment, use the root elements id as id in your replace call.

Comment: 1st parameter is xml id of baseActivity from which i am trying to call..there's no need of calling xml id

Comment: first parameter? 0? your id is 0? that seems odd.

Comment: no actually id -takes as integer from (R.Layout./////).so i have tried to put zero as it is of integer type

Comment: YES I GOT THE ANSWER JUST USE getId() in first argumnt